# Brew doctor complains about 2 unbrewed dylibs (possibly remnants from Samsung Sidesync)

Tags: macos, homebrew, dynamic-library

I've just found that brew doctor gives me the following error :

```
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
    /usr/local/lib/LibSideSyncOSX9.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/ss_conn_lib.dylib
```

I am suspected that these are remnants of Samsung Sidesync program that I tried to use recently but it never worked, so I uninstalled it (using iTrash).
Should I manually remove those two libraries or not(one of them is 1.7mb)?
Thank you.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/235006/brew-doctor-complains-about-2-unbrewed-dylibs-possibly-remnants-from-samsung-si/345714#345714

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should remove them. Package managers will complain if there are files installed in the area they manage. So with Homebrew only Homebrew installed files should be in /usr/local

In this case I would guess from the names the first is definitely from Sidesync but the second could also be used by others

Comment: These two files have the same creation date (Oct-12-2015) so they probably belong to the same program.

Answer (score 0):

Those files are installed by [Samsung SideSync](https://www.samsung.com/us/sidesync/).